# Azure Container Web App Increase 10 Second Timeout

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I see that people usually say the max request timeout is 240 seconds, but on my Container for Webapps app service, the max request time is 10 seconds before resulting in a 500 error.

Is there a way to increase this lower 10 second max to be closer to the true max of 240 sec?

Comment: Are you sure your 500 error is being caused by a timeout?

Comment: @SamAxe Yes. it loops over a CSV and at smaller row counts it works fine. If I upload a short CSV, it times out after 10 sec.

Comment: Can you try some sort of sleep operation in the api implementation and check again? I am expecting there might be some other issue than 10 sec timeout (maybe memory issue or something else which is giving 500)

Comment: @Atul, with a sleep it does the same thing.

Comment: @grepsedawk - in the sample api you did no computation but just sleep and still it timedout after 10 sec?

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the amount of time for Azure App Service custom container by setting the WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT App Setting to the value you want.

Default Value = **230** Sec.

Max Value= **1800** Sec

Hope [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#custom-containers) documentation helps.

Comment: This variable is related to docker image boot, not http request timeouts.